# Как правильно использовать структуру проекта в crm, когда у одного клиента может быть миллион заявок?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, crm

Как правильно использовать структуру проекта в crm, когда у одного клиента может быть миллион заявок, своих клиентов, других данных.
Я например для каждого клиента в crm создаю динамически свою бд и при обращении он работает только со своей бд а не общей.

Теперь вот думаю, правильно ли сделал или всё-таки для crm нужна одна бд для всех клиентов?
Приведем в пример амо crm или Битрикс.

Comment: Не смотрели в сторону функций, возвращающих табличное значение? Select из функции в которую передаете в качестве параметра Id клиента и он будет видеть только свои данные (по id можно внутри функции выдавать все, что угодно). Просто меня смущает - отдельную бд для всех клиентов - даже для мёртвых- это такое )) опять же, чтобы собрать статистику по всем клиентам - надо каждый раз лезть в системные представления, чтобы получить список всех бд - тоже - такое ))))

Comment: В mysql не уверен (мало опыта), но в mssql это itvf, а в oracle - pipelined functions. В зависимости от версии mssql есть ещё row level security, но это уже сложнее.